# Field collection views - How to make a reverse relaionship?

Tags: entities

I am having difficulty finding the way to grab data from a referencing node.

**CONTENT TYPES AND FIELDS**

1. Content type "Referenced"
2. Content type "Referencing" with a field collection with these fields:

   - "Referenced item" - An Entity reference field to the "Referenced" content type.
   - "Note" - A simple text field

**VIEWS**

1. A view of type "Field collection item" - this is the view to be
   embedded.
2. A view of a regular type ("Node") with a field to use the
   inner view (Formatter: "View field-collection items") - this is the
   embedding view. This view has a contextual filter of nid in order to
   print it in Content type A.

**NEED**

In a view of type "Field collection item" - how do I fetch the data of the content type "Referencing"? Here are the fields needed:

- Title
- Note
- Path

I have tried probably everything except the way it should work... Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: When you created the view, did you select "field collection items" as its content source? Try doing that, and then create a relationship to its referenced entity.

Comment: Hi, yes, this have been done.

Also, here are exports of the 2 views - first is the embedded one: http://pastebin.com/zGF6gGeb

Still need help, thanks!